# how to custom position jquery-ui tooltip for each item

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

I use default code to apply for all website have tag img or attribute is tootltip and title

```
$(document).tooltip({
        track: true,
        items: "img, [tooltip], [title]",
        content: function() {
            var element = $( this );

            if ( element.is("[tooltip]") ) {
                var src = element.attr("tooltip");
                return "<img src='" + src + "' width='100'>";
            }
            if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                return element.attr( "title" );
            }
            if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
                return element.attr( "alt" );
            }   
        }
    });
```

but in the some cases, I want to change position for another tag name.  Example: with tags that have class="custome" it's will be change another position my and at, converse it's use default position. How to do it?

Sr, my english is not good